# How do I count the power of a number in my for loop in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, primes

I'm created a program that does prime factorization. However, I need the output to contain power of  prime numbers so instead of the output being: 2.2.2.3, it should be 2^3.3

The only problem is that the exponents aren't what they should be. I don't know where the mistake is.

Here's my for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num, val, i, prime=0, check, check2, count=0, counter=1;
    while(num != 0){
        printf("\nInput number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        val=num;
        for(i=2; i<=num; i++){
            if(num%i==0){
                count++;
                if(count==1 && val!=i){
                    check=i;
                }
                else if(val!=i){
                    check2=i;
                }
                else{
                    prime=1;
                    printf("%d is prime", val);
                }
                num/=i;
                if(check==check2){
                    counter++;
                }
                if(prime==0){
                    if(count==1){
                        if(counter==1)
                            printf("%d", i);
                        else
                            printf("%d^%d", i, counter);
                    } else if(check!=check2){
                        if(counter==1)
                            printf(".%d", i);
                        else
                            printf(".%d^%d", check2, counter);
                        counter=1;
                    }
                }
                i=1;
            }
            prime=0;
        }
        counter=1;
        printf("\n-------------------");
        count=0;
    }
    printf("-------------------\nEnd");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first mistake is that you didn't initialize ```num```.

Comment: second mistake: you do not use functions

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the solution was quite simple. I'm counting the power with another for loop that checks how many times I can divide by that number.

```
for(i=2; i<=num; i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            for(i; num%i==0; count++){
                num/=i;
            }
            printf("%d %d", i, count);
            i=1;
            count=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't reset `count` twice. Do it once, just before the point of use. Done your way it looks like a bug at first sight: harder to read.